# AS3 calling function from .as file to .fla not in static class

Tags: function, actionscript-3, flash

need some help and its driving me nuts! I am calling a function from my .as file and have done quite a bit of research on it it looks as though I am doing it all right but apparently I am not.

I am trying to call the startFoxtel(); function from my .as into my .fla but it keeps coming back with

1061: Call to a possibly undefined method startFoxtel through a reference with static type NGVTVAir. (Symbol 'FoxtelContainer', Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 29)  NGVTVAir.fla

This is on the .fla (please bare in mind I have removed all other irrelevant functions and it is purely the startFoxtel call that it doesn't like)

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.Tween;

var NGVTV:NGVTVAir = new NGVTVAir();

function FoxDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  NGVTV.startFoxtel();
  var twAlpha:Tween = new Tween(MovieClip(root).bg1,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,3,true);
  var tw1Alpha:Tween = new Tween(MovieClip(root).buttons,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,3,true);
  var tw2Alpha:Tween = new Tween(MovieClip(root).logo,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,3,true);
  var tw3Alpha:Tween = new Tween(MovieClip(root).cityscape,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,3,true);
  twAlpha.start();
  tw1Alpha.start();
  tw2Alpha.start();
  tw3Alpha.start();
}
```

this is on the .as

```
package
{
import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.NativeProcessExitEvent;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.filesystem.File;

public class NGVTVAir
{
    public var process:NativeProcess;
    public var dispatch:EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

    public function StartFoxtel():void
    {
        if(NativeProcess.isSupported)
        {
            setupAndLaunchFoxtel();
        }
        else
        {
            trace("NativeProcess not supported.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, reread your code. you're trying to call `startFoxtel` but that function doesn't exist in your .as file. What does exist though is the function `StartFoxtel`. With a capital **S**.

Comment: thanks Dodger, I cannot believe I missed that... feeling a bit stupid right about now.

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us :-)

Comment: There's already a lot that is wrong with your code. You can't use Tween class that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS3 is case sensitive :

You need to replace

```
NGVTV.startFoxtel();
```

To match your function name

```
public function StartFoxtel():void
```

So it would be

```
NGVTV.StartFoxtel();
```

Comment: Thanks Blue, yeah Dodger got me sorted out :) can't believe I missed that spent half a day constantly looking over my code and completely missed that.